# need to use an asmx webservice(wsdl) in c# to update and delete from this xml file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, wsdl, asmx

I need to use an asmx webservice(wsdl) in c# to update and delete from this xml file

```
enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StudentRecords>
<student>
<id>1</id>
<cohort>BSE</cohort>`enter code here`
<firstname>Sherlock</firstname>
<lastname>Holmes</lastname>
<address>United Kingdom</address>
</student>

<student>
<id>2</id>
<cohort>BSE</cohort>
<firstname>Tom</firstname>
<lastname>Hanks</lastname>
<address>United Kingdom</address>
</student>
</StudentRecords>
```

Comment: what is the question!

Comment: The question is i need create a webservice in c# using wsdl to add, update and delete new element(student in this case). So far, managed to add and consume in a client page...im stuck with update and delete

Comment: Which elements need updating?  Do you need to delete all students or just specific.?

Comment: one student in fact..an onclick event will consume this method of edit or delete...when i click it calls that method in webservice and edit or delete one student(gridview in client)

Answer (score 0):

used this method for add 
`enter code here`

```
      [WebMethod]
      public string Insert(string i, string c, string f, string l, string a)
      {

        XmlDocument xl = new XmlDocument();
        xl.Load(Server.MapPath("~/student.xml"));

        XmlElement parent = xl.CreateElement("student");
        XmlElement id = xl.CreateElement("id");
        XmlElement cohort = xl.CreateElement("cohort");
        XmlElement fname = xl.CreateElement("firstname");
        XmlElement lname = xl.CreateElement("lastname");
        XmlElement add = xl.CreateElement("address");

        id.InnerText = i;
        cohort.InnerText = c;
        fname.InnerText = f;
        lname.InnerText = l;
        add.InnerText = a;

        parent.AppendChild(id);
        parent.AppendChild(cohort);
        parent.AppendChild(fname);
        parent.AppendChild(lname);
        parent.AppendChild(add);

        xl.DocumentElement.AppendChild(parent);
        xl.Save(Server.MapPath("~/student.xml"));
        LoadData();



        return i.ToString()+ c.ToString() + f.ToString() + l.ToString() + 
        a.ToString();
       }
```